# Is it possible to use conditional types on object or array of objects

Tags: typescript

I'd like to decide a function return type based on object or array of the objects as input. For example, if input is object, an object is expected as function return type. However if input is array of objects, then an array is expected as return type.

`type ObjectOrArray<T extends T | T[]> = Array.isArray(T) ? T[] : T`

The code above is obviously not working, but I am wondering if it's possible to create this type using Typescript conditional types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TypeScript, you test if a type is an array by using `extends unknown[]`

```
type IfArray<T, A, B> = T extends unknown[] ? A : B;
```

The `unknown[]` means you don't need to know what type is inside the array, you are just checking whether the type itself is an array.

Another possibility is making sure a type is an array:

```
type AsArray<T> = T extends unknown[] ? T : T[];
```

Comment: A and B look unnecessary: You can do: `type IfArray<T> = T extends unknown[] ? T : T[];` Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, I was missing something, obviously. I read the question as: I want an array type if it is not, otherwise return the array type.

Answer (score 1):

```
type ObjectOrArray<T> = T extends (infer U)[] ? U[] : T;
```

Infer will retrieve the type of the array.

```
type Person = {firstname:string;lastname:string}
type Poeple = Array<Person>;
type D = ObjectOrArray<Person>; // person
type C = ObjectOrArray<Poeple>; // person[]
```

for the function when you say

> I'd like to decide a function return type based on object or array of the objects as input. For example, if input is object, an object is expected as function return type. However if input is array of objects, then an array is expected as return type.

```
const doNothing = <T>(param: T): T => {
    return param
};
```

Generics will do exactly that, you don't need any conditional types.

```
const me : Person = {firstname:"romain", lastname:"taillandier"}
const resultForObject = doNothing(me); // person
const resultForArray = doNothing([me]); // person[]
```

last if you need to build an array based on one element or many

```
const buildArray = <K>(param: ObjectOrArray<K>): Array<K> => {
    return Array.isArray(param) ? param : [param as K];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to define a [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#handbook-content) return type for a function depending on it's input argument. From my experience it's usually a good idea to use [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) for this.

```
declare function whatever<T extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>>(arg: T): T;
declare function whatever<T extends unknown[]>(arg: T): T;
declare function whatever<T extends unknown[] | Record<PropertyKey, unknown>>(
  arg: T,
): T;

const a = whatever(["some", "array"]);
//    ^? const a: string[]
const b = whatever({ some: "object" });
//    ^? const b: { some: string }
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwHcALKDEANxBgB4AVeEADzNWAGd4AlcHGYagAowcAByoYAngGkQEgDTw0Aa1Q4CqAHwaAFLADmALni0AlEdoBuAFChIsBCnTY8hEmUo16TFu0WoVaqgA2gC6OvrmZsbWttBwSGiYuPjEpBRUdAzMIKwcyqrqofAAPlw8fILCYjCSMvJ%20Aepa2lbw8BHGclZRllZWYHhsGO3wALyuaR7aQQBEbDgAtiAzCjOwMFASMyEm1gD0e21tAHoA-P2DwwBGYxPuVNoA3vDzS0YzOFcAVuAYM-AAX12VgOR3gZysQA)